# $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. $G$ is a point of intersection of its diagonals and if $O$ is any point show that: OA+OB+OC+OD=4OG

Tags: geometry, vectors

I am stuck in this problem. Please help me. All theres a parallelogram and we have to prove is $\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}=4\vec{OG}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Pleas show your working and use Mathjax if you want a higher chance of somebody answering your question.

Comment: First draw a diagram.  Let ${\bf a},{\bf b},{\bf c}$ be the vectors from $O$ to $A,B,C$.  Using geometric facts you know about parallelograms, figure out $OD$ and $OG$ in terms of these.  Then check the equation.

Comment: Hint: use that $G$ is the midpoint of $AC$ to show that $\vec{OA}+\vec{OC} = 2 \vec{OG}\,$. Repeat. Add together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $$4\vec{OG}=\left(\vec{OA}+\vec{AG}\right)+\left(\vec{OB}+\vec{BG}\right)+\left(\vec{OC}+\vec{CG}\right)+\left(\vec{OD}+\vec{DG}\right)=$$
$$=\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}+\left(\vec{AG}+\vec{CG}\right)+\left(\vec{BG}+\vec{DG}\right)=$$
$$=\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}.$$